# Updating progressbar in AsyncTask slows the uploading speed

Tags: android

I'm using AsyncTask to upload an image to webserver, when I impelement a method to update the progressbar, it slow down the uploading.But without the loop updater for progressbar it uploads the image in few seconds (very fast). Here is the code that i use to update the progressbar :

```
  bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
  mFileLen =  file.length();

  for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
                publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) mFileLen) * 100));
            }
```

Is there anyway i can update the progressbar without leading to slow down the operation ?

Comment: There's a lot of missing context here. At what point is this code called? Why are you iterating through an entire buffer each time? Why do you set the progressBar maximum to the same value over and over in the loop? Why are you storing and then discarding `i` in a variable called `progress`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ideas:

1. You don't need to set the `progressBar1` max on each iteration of the loop, it's pointless since `bufferSize` doesn't change inside the loop. Move that command outside the loop.
2. try to remember your previous progress: `prevProgress = (i / mFileLen)`. Then measure your new progress: `currProgress = (i / mFileLen)`. Then, if the difference between the two progresses isn't greater than 0.01 (1%), don't update the UI: `if (currProgress - prevProgress >= 0.01) publishProgress(...);`

Here's an example:

```
        float currProgress = 0;
        float prevProgress = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) 
        {
            currProgress = ((float)i / (float) mFileLen);

            if (currProgress - prevProgress >= 0.01)
            {
                publishProgress((int) (currProgress * 100));
                prevProgress = currProgress;
            }
        }
```

You could make it work even faster by updating the UI when the progress is larger than 2% (0.02) rather than 1% (0.01), etc.

Also, I'm feeling that there's no real correlation between `i` and `mFileLen`... What's your `bufferSize`? Is it less than `mFileLen` (it should be). In this case, you should use a separate variable to count the overall progress it use that instead of `i` to measure the progress.

Hope this helps.

Comment: About the first point I admit that was a stupid move and it may slow down the uploading while it update the UI. So i moved it outside the loop but it seems the same issue. About the second point, I will have a look. Many thanks ...

Comment: when you said "try to remember" i didn't realy get that !! could you please exaplin more. because placing both `prev` and `curr` in same loop looks unfunctional, and it dosen't update the progressbar at all.

Comment: I see what you did there, great example. And yes i think they hold seperated values, i'll try to use a seperated variable... thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

As a reminder, you can send data to a web server in an IntentService, which is also asynchronous. An IntentService is preferred if the user doesn't immediately have to do work with the results of the operation. It's completely background. On the other hand, you can post notifications from it. Ask yourself these questions:

1. Do I want this operation to continue, even if the user changes the device orientation? (Asynctask will stop if the Activity is destroyed; IntentService won't).
2. Conversely, do I mind if the operation has to reload (AsyncTask is a bit more simple).
3. Am I storing persistent data (Use an IntentService or even a bound Service and a SyncAdapter)
4. Does the user need to stick around while the operation completes (if yes, an AsyncTask gives more immediate feedback when its finished. If no, an IntentService is somewhat disconnected from the app's Activities, so it can churn along merrily while other stuff is happening.

Comment: After the upload is done i have to push some data to the main UI, is the IntentService able to do so ? if yes... is it also able to update the main UI while the uploading is in progress? about the orientation i had already tested that but for some how it doesn't inntrepute the AsyncTask... not sure if the upload goes so fast before the oritation is done.... from my view i think the right chose here is AsyncTask .. because before the uploading i decode$encode the image so it have less size... so the uploading is happning very fast while the user have his eyes on the activity without leaving it.